# How does Javascript form.submit() method works?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I want to scrap a website that changes content after modifying a `<select>` that has an attribute `onchange="this.form.submit()"`.  So I need to know how `form.submit()` works so I can simulate it.

Answer (score 0):

All it does is submit the parent form as would normally happen if you clicked a `<input type="submit" />` button.

Comment: And you can tell me how this works and how can I simulate it?

Comment: @user1513091 It is a method that is built into javascript.  There is no 'how it works'.  If you want to know how it works, look into the source code that actually defines javascript.